# Not able to deploy springboot application in an external tomcat

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, tomcat

While trying to deploy a springboot application in an external tomcat, I'm not able to deploy. In the pom.xml ,if i exclude tomcat dependency then im not facing compile time error. Since i have used tomcat jar classes in my project. Please let me know how to deploy the project.

Comment: Why do you need an external tomcat? Why an embedded one doesn't fit?

Comment: Can you post the main method?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue as you and I came with a solution. It's maybe not the best, but it works...

First you need two application :

**Application.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

**WarApplication**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class WarApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(WarApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WarApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

After this you need to modify you `pom.xml` with this :

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>tomcat</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <project.packaging>war</project.packaging>
            <project.start-class>com.whatever.WarApplication</project.start-class>
        </properties>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>

    <profile>
        <id>springboot</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <project.packaging>jar</project.packaging>
            <project.start-class>com.whatever.Application</project.start-class>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>

<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Package as an executable jar/war -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <profiles>
                        <profile>tomcat</profile>
                        <profile>springboot</profile>
                    </profiles>
                    <mainClass>${project.start-class}</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Basically, you are just making profiles depending on where you have to deploy. But if you only need to deploy on tomcat, you could remove the profiles. What is **important** in this pom, it's the `<scope>provided</scope>` in the tomcat profile. [Here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html) is the link to *Traditional Deployment* from Spring doc.

Answer (score 1):

As an addition @Gableg's answer,

in pom.xml :

`<packaging>war</packaging>`  set as war not jar.

Basically @Gableg's two condition and my condition i specified above is enough.
Tree condition is enough to make an app deployable in external tomcat.

I referenced the video in below.It is really usable.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=05EKZ9Xmfws