# Unable to run my SpringBoot project on traditional tomcat

Tags: java, spring-boot

We have two SpringBoot projects **project1**(usermgmt) and **project2**(instrumentsetup). As we need to use the service and entities from project1 in project2, we packaged project1 as **jar**
and added that project1 jar under 'lib' folder of project2 (war)-root directory.

In pom.xml of project2, added below 'dependency' and 'plugin' for the same.

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.xyz</groupId>
<artifactId>usermgmt</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>            
<!-- <scope>system</scope>
<systemPath>${basedir}/lib/usermgmt-1.0.0.jar</systemPath> -->
</dependency>


<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>                  
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>install-external</id>
            <phase>clean</phase>
            <configuration>
                <file>${basedir}/lib/usermgmt_1.jar</file>
                <repositoryLayout>default</repositoryLayout>
                <groupId>com.xyz</groupId>
                <artifactId>usermgmt</artifactId>
                <packaging>jar</packaging>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <generatePom>true</generatePom>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>install-file</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Our main class of project2 contains the following:

> com.xyz.usermgmt

-- project1 package

> com.xyz.instrumentsetup

--- project2 package

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.xyz.usermgmt","com.xyz.instrumentsetup"})
@EntityScan({"com.xyz.usermgmt","com.xyz.instrumentsetup"})
@EnableJpaRepositories({"com.xyz.usermgmt","com.xyz.instrumentsetup"})
public class InstrumentsetupApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements WebMvcConfigurer 
{   

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(InstrumentsetupApplication.class);
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(InstrumentsetupApplication.class).child(UsermgmtApplication.class).logStartupInfo(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        log.info("Start of instrument setup");
        ApplicationContext ctx = new SpringApplicationBuilder(InstrumentsetupApplication.class, UsermgmtApplication.class).run(args);


        log.info("context created in instrument setup:" + ctx);
    }

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**").allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE");
    }     

}
```

Now our problem is that, this scenario works fine with embedded tomcat but not with traditional tomcat.
We created war of project2 using **sts-4** and tried to deploy that war in **tomcat 8.0**. 
Our jdk version - **jdk1.8.0_201**

### **error:**

```
20-Jun-2019 17:41:08.491 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
20-Jun-2019 17:41:17.183 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/llelnweb]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:940)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1816)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on com.xyz.instrumentsetup.instrumentrights.model.InstrumentRights.user references an unknown entity: com.xyz.usermgmt.users.model.Users
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1778)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1105)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316)
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:139)
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.configureAsChildIfNecessary(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:152)
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.build(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:171)
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.build(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:161)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:124)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:91)
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5240)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on com.xyz.instrumentsetup.instrumentrights.model.InstrumentRights.user references an unknown entity: com.xyz.usermgmt.users.model.Users
    at org.hibernate.cfg.ToOneFkSecondPass.doSecondPass(ToOneFkSecondPass.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processEndOfQueue(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1827)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processFkSecondPassesInOrder(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1771)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1658)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:287)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:904)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:935)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1837)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1774)
    ... 32 more

20-Jun-2019 17:41:17.183 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Error deploying web application archive C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\webapps\llelnweb.war
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/llelnweb]]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:940)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1816)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

20-Jun-2019 17:41:17.193 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\webapps\llelnweb.war has finished in 24,216 ms
20-Jun-2019 17:41:17.193 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\webapps\docs
20-Jun-2019 17:41:17.244 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\webapps\docs has finished in 51 ms
20-Jun-2019 17:41:17.244 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\webapps\ELNweb
20-Jun-2019 17:41:17.291 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\webapps\ELNweb has finished in 47 ms
20-Jun-2019 17:41:17.291 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\webapps\host-manager
20-Jun-2019 17:41:17.332 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\webapps\host-manager has finished in 41 ms
20-Jun-2019 17:41:17.342 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\webapps\manager
20-Jun-2019 17:41:17.392 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\webapps\manager has finished in 60 ms
20-Jun-2019 17:41:17.392 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\webapps\ROOT
20-Jun-2019 17:41:17.425 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\webapps\ROOT has finished in 33 ms
20-Jun-2019 17:41:17.435 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
20-Jun-2019 17:41:17.445 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
20-Jun-2019 17:41:17.445 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 24547 ms
```

---

Hope someone could guide us in resolving out the issue.
Thanks in advance
Subashini

Comment: Have you checked inside your generated WAR file if the "missing" entity is really there?

Comment: Yes, its there inside the "jar" of that generated "war".

Answer (score 0):

Which version of spring boot you are using? Latest version requires tomcat 9.

Comment: SpringBoot 2.1.5. I tried with Tomcat 9 also.Same issue

Comment: This answer should be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>` and you want to deploy your app on a traditionnal Tomcat, you will have to tell in the `build` section of your `pom.xml` to use the provided Tomcat (`<scope>provided</scope>`). Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53885604/not-able-to-deploy-springboot-application-in-an-external-tomcat/53888846#53888846) for my solution or [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html) for the Spring docs for traditionnal deployment.

I may be wrong because it's the first time I see that the problem come from an unknown class reference.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion GabLeg. Looked into link.Plz find below my pom.xml for war project. Tomcat<provided> is already there.But still its not working.

Comment: Sorry unable to attach pom.xml in comments section. But already contains tomcat dependency under <dependencies> but not under<profiles>.